# How are these mathematical expressions read?

Tags: expressions, mathematics

[image]

Hi, can you please help me with reading of these expressions?
The first one could be: sum of n plus one above the sum of k plus one?
The second: five above two equals five factorial divided by the multiplication of factorial of difference five minus two times two factorial
I have no idea with the third.
Fourth: x(with comma?) is larger or equal to x(??)

Thanks for help!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about the English Language and should be on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If you're a mathematicians, the first one is most likely read "en plus one choose kay plus one." It is most definitely ***not*** "sum"; the operation is that of taking a binomial coefficient, while the word "sum" means addition. And, similarly, the left-hand-side of the second is read "five choose two".

Comment: In 3 I'd call them "a tilde" and "a hat"; in 4 "x **prime**" and "x double (prime)". (Physics background)

Comment: @Peter you're looking at a contextually probable utilisation of the column vector / 2-by-1 matrix in the first example. This doesn't generalise.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I'm assuming the parentheses in the first and the second equation mean the same thing. The second one is definitely read "five choose two".

Comment: Yes, a contextually probable utilisation (though there's only one equation so far).

Comment: Note that while this *is* a maths question, and *would* be on-topic on Math.SE, it's only on-topic there because their principal language is English. It's basically a "what's this thing called in English" question, which is on topic here (although — notwithstanding the good answer here — you might get better answers in a more specialist environment).

Comment: The first is (as said in earlier comments) a column vector; the second a notation for combinations of 2 items taken from 5; the third and fourth comparative expressions. This is not about English. It is about conventions for vocalizing mathematical notation; the vocalizing is secondary to the notation and the question should be moved.

Answer (score 4):

These, like most mathematics, are not really meant to be read aloud, and can be read in any language, though with independent traditions. Mathematical language is not limited to any single spoken language, and is only fully part of written language.

Here's how *I* would say them aloud  in English, if I **had** to.

Peter Shor pointed out that the first two involve binomial coefficients:

1. "N plus one, choose K plus one"
   (though there are lots of other things it could mean, and therefore other ways to say it)
2. "Five, choose two, equals factorial five over factorial quantity five minus two, times factorial 2"
   (a rather silly equation, since it's not remotely close to lowest terms;
   and it's also hard to phrase for speaking aloud -- you have to use intonation)

In the second two, the ordering relation takes an optional *is*; it's not optional in normal English, but it is when speaking formulae:

3. "A-tilde (is) less than or equal to A-hat"
   (both A-terms are ad hoc, since these aren't mathematical symbols)
4. "X-prime (is) greater than or equal to X-double-prime"

Comment: And I see the comments have filled in while I was typing this.